# c++ function with test scores 0-100

Tags: c++

my if statement is not 100% working, i am not sure what I did wrong in it .Any help will be appreciated, thank you! here is my function

```
void DisplayStudentsInRange(const StudentType student[], int numStudents, int lownum, int highnum)
{
    cout <<"Enter two values from 0-100 for the range of test scores you want to view: ";
    cin >> lownum >> highnum;

    if ( lownum < 0 || highnum < 0 || lownum > highnum || lownum > 100 || highnum > 100)
    {
        cout <<"Please re-enter 2 values of test scores that you want to view from within the range 0-100";
        cin >> lownum >> highnum;
    }

    cout << endl << "List of students with scores in the range " << lownum << " to " << highnum << endl << endl;
    FormatNameScoreGrade(cout);


    for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
    {
        if(student[i].testScore >= lownum && student[i].testScore <= highnum)
        {

            cout << setw(20) << student[i].studentName << setw(10) << student[i].testScore << setw(10) << student[i].grade << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Also, which if statement?

Comment: I personally don't like cin for collecting user input because it always leaves \n in buffer as unread input - this is a bad design. This behavior always interferes with next input; you have to pay special attention when using cin and pass control flow to other code that is not controlled by yourself.

Comment: "my if statement is not 100% working" - what's working and what isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use parenthesis in your if statement

```
if ( (lownum < 0) || (highnum < 0) || (lownum > highnum) || (lownum > 100) || (highnum > 100))
```

I have had problems when I didn't do that in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're after but concerning the first `if` statement, you probably want to fit the input and the validation inside a loop :

```
do {
    values = get_input();
} while (!values_are_valid());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what
If isn't proper also just a note 
You first if will work only once if second time data is entered incorrectly 
You won't ask user for reenter it, 
In case that you want to get correct input 
You should replace your first if with a while.

But overall it would be better to use

```
 Do {
     cout <<"Enter two values from 0-100 for the range of test scores you want to view: ";
     cin >> lownum >> highnum;
     }while( (lownum < 0) || (highnum < 0) || (lownum > highnum) || (lownum > 100) || (highnum > 100)); //statement
```

Do will run for the first time as is , then if the input was incorrect while statement will trigger the do part once the input is correct.
you can edit the couts to be like "Enter/ReEnter" etc..

Comment: your right about that, i just noticed if i enter the incorrect data the 2nd time it still takes it. I tried the do-while but it go throughs even though I put the correct range the first time?